# Ansible Read csv file and encrypt passwords, output of command to file

Tags: ansible

I have a csv file containing ip addresses and passwords. These passwords need to be encrypted and written to a file.

This is what I have tried so far:

```yaml
- name: Read csv file
  read_csv:
    path: files/ww.csv
    fieldnames: ip,password
    delimiter: ','
  register: routers
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: encrypt password
  command: "ansible-vault encrypt_string --vault-password-file password '{{ router.password }}' --name 'password'"
  loop: "{{ routers.list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: router
  register: "output"
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: write file
  copy:
     content: "{{ output.stdout }}"
     dest: "/tmp/{{ router.ip }}.yaml"
  loop: "{{ routers.list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: router
  delegate_to: localhost
```

I want to use `output.stdout` but I get the following error:

```
TASK [robustel : write file] *********************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.41.1.161]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/ansible/roles/routers/tasks/create_var_files.yaml': line 20, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: write file\n  ^ here\n"}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering a variable on a task with a loop. This changes the structure of the data as described in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop). Debugging `output` would have given you a clue.

`output.results` is a list where each element contains a `stdout` key (e.g. the first one being `output.results.0.stdout`). Moreover, each element also contains an `item` key containing the original element in the loop that was registered.

Modifying your last task like below should give you the expected result:

```yaml
- name: write file
  copy:
    content: "{{ output_result.stdout }}"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ output_result.item.ip }}.yaml"
  loop: "{{ output.results }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: output_result
  delegate_to: localhost
```